Resolving issue with Atoms Not Assigned Properly using atom_style full
Greetings Matter Modeling,
I'm getting an error when using atom_style full. 25 out of 30 atoms import properly. I recently started using atom_style full building up the model.
phill@phillcube:~/Desktop/Scripts/LAMMPS/newCIF$ mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus -np 8 lmp_mpi -in /home/phill/Desktop/Scripts/LAMMPS/newCIF/testing.lmp
LAMMPS (7 Feb 2024 - Update 1)
Reading data file ...
  triclinic box = (0 0 0) to (4.99 4.3214668 17.0615) with tilt (-2.495 0 0)
WARNING: Triclinic box skew is large. LAMMPS will run inefficiently. (../domain.cpp:219)
  2 by 1 by 4 MPI processor grid
  reading atoms ...
  25 atoms
ERROR: Did not assign all atoms correctly (../read_data.cpp:1443)
Last command: read_data CaCO3.lmp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[57814,1],5]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here's my input file:
# CaCO3.lmp input file

# Calcite - Ca C O3
30 atoms
3 atom types

0.000000000000 4.990000000000 xlo xhi
0.000000000000 4.321466764884 ylo yhi
0.000000000000 17.061500000000 zlo zhi
-2.495000000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 xy xz yz

Masses

1 40.07800000 # Ca
2 12.01100000 # C
3 15.99900000 # O

Atoms # full

1 1 1 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 2.0
2 1 2 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 4.265375000000 1.5
3 1 3 1.286422000000 0.000000000000 4.265375000000 -1.1667
4 1 3 -0.643211000000 1.114074131987 4.265375000000 -1.1667
5 1 3 1.851789000000 3.207392632897 4.265375000000 -1.1667

6 2 1 2.497495000000 1.439048432706 5.681479500000 2.0
7 2 2 2.497495000000 1.439048432706 9.946854500000 1.5
8 2 3 3.783917000000 1.439048432706 9.946854500000 -1.1667
9 2 3 1.206083000000 1.439048432706 1.416104500000 -1.1667
10 2 3 3.140706000000 0.324974300719 1.416104500000 -1.1667

11 3 1 -0.002495000000 2.882418332178 11.380020500000 2.0
12 3 2 -0.002495000000 2.882418332178 15.645395500000 1.5
13 3 3 1.283927000000 2.882418332178 15.645395500000 -1.1667
14 3 3 -0.645706000000 3.996492464165 15.645395500000 -1.1667
15 3 3 1.854284000000 2.553122564694 9.946854500000 -1.1667

16 4 1 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 8.530750000000 2.0
17 4 2 0.000000000000 0.000000000000 12.796125000000 1.5
18 4 3 0.643211000000 1.114074131987 12.796125000000 -1.1667
19 4 3 -0.643211000000 1.114074131987 4.265375000000 -1.1667
20 4 3 1.851789000000 0.329295767484 9.946854500000 -1.1667

21 5 1 2.495000000000 1.443369899471 14.212229500000 2.0
22 5 2 2.495000000000 1.443369899471 1.416104500000 1.5
23 5 3 3.138211000000 2.557444031459 1.416104500000 -1.1667
24 5 3 1.206083000000 1.439048432706 1.416104500000 -1.1667
25 5 3 3.703578000000 0.000000000000 12.796125000000 -1.1667

26 6 1 0.000000000000 2.878096865413 2.849270500000 2.0
27 6 2 0.000000000000 2.878096865413 7.114645500000 1.5
28 6 3 0.643211000000 3.992170997400 7.114645500000 -1.1667
29 6 3 -1.283927000000 2.882418332178 7.114645500000 -1.1667
30 6 3 3.140706000000 0.324974300719 1.416104500000 -1.1667

I'm conducting a phonon catalytic approach to calcination for post-combustion industrial lime production and regeneration of lime-based Direct Air Capture sorbents. The goal is to reduce bulk operational temperatures by several hundred Kelvin through selective heating of an individual vibrational mode's temperature (phonon catalysis).
Any idea why I'm getting this error?

+1 but please use a proper code block.
